# Two Method "Hold Down Button" in Cocoa Touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have two hold down buttons, Right next to each other. One covering the right half of the iOS screen and the other covering the left half of the screen. The code for them is (opposite coordinate related values for left methods):

```
- (IBAction)RightStart:(id)sender {//Touch Event is TOUCH DOWN

    RightTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:RightSpeed target:self selector:@selector(RightMove) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] ;
    if(RightTimer == nil){
        RightTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:RightSpeed target:self selector:@selector(RightMove) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] ;
    }
}

- (IBAction)RightStop:(id)sender {  //Touch Event is TOUCH UP INSIDE

    [RightTimer invalidate] ;
    RightTimer = nil ;
}

- (void)RightMove{
    Player.center = CGPointMake(Player.center.x + 1,Player.center.y) ;
    if(Player.center.x > 304){
        Player.center = CGPointMake(304, Player.center.y) ;
    }
}
```

When the user holds their finger (my mouse) on one of the buttons and slides it across to the other button, the image moves to one side of the screen and stays there(because there is a lock so it can't move of the screen).

It appears, from breakpoints, that when the mouse/finger is swept off of the button without actually releasing from the screen, that the stop method is never run. When then trying to move the other way, say left, to get it off the side, it moves 1 pixel to the left, then 1 to the right, etc. Because holding down left starts the left timer and the right timer is running too, the image doesn't move.

How should I solve the problem that the program does not recognize that the finger has left the button when it is held down on the button, but swiped off, using a Two Function hold down button?

Comment: Try getting the finger location in `touches moved` methods of `UIView` and check using `CGRectContainsPoint()`. use a `boolean` value to manipulate the moves.

Comment: You can  also set the `sent action` of button to `touchDragOutside`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, similar to what @Abhishek Bedi said, make a new IBAction method that is the same as the RightStop method, however uses the touchDragExit action.